# What is the root of $\sum _{i=1}^{m-1} i^k=m^k$ given integer k?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, riemann-zeta, mathematica, polygamma

Let $m'$ be the root of $\sum _{i=1}^{m-1} i^k=m^k$ given integer $k$ (solving for $m$).
What is $m'$?

Comment: That scattering looks to me like the result of computer rounding in the intermediate calculations, rather than something relevant to your problem. Subtracting two nearly equal numbers loses a lot of precision.

Comment: Good point on the scattering. In addition to subtracting nearly equal numbers, I'm using Mathematica's FindRoot, which warns me of the low working precision, so I'm doing model fitting on data that is already approximate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment; May be this idea can be useful:

Suppose $(i, k)=1$ then due to FLT:

$i^k\equiv i\mod k$  and we may write:

$$1^k+2^k+3^k+4^k+ . . . (m-1)^k\equiv(1+2+3+4+ . . .m-1) \mod k$$

Or:

$$\begin{equation} \sum^{m-1}_{i=1}i^k\equiv\frac{m(m-1)}2 \mod k =k.t+\frac{m(m-1)}2=m^k\end{equation}$$

Note that in the case i=1 , i and k are not coprime but with some manipulation we can get similar result.

$$m(2m^{k-1}-m+1)=2kt$$

Solution of this equation can give m and k. For example to ease the solution we may let m=k for a particular case, then:

$$2m^{m-1}-m+1=2t$$

m must be odd, let $m=2s+1$ we have:

$$2(2s+1)^{2s}-2s=2t$$

This Diophantine equation may have integer solutions , hence we may find m and k.